# Bash Script not running on browser

Tags: php, bash, imagemagick

Here is my bash script file in `/usr/bin/`

```
#!/bin/sh
convert source.jpg -define jpeg:extent=256kb destination.jpg;
```

and my php code is:

```
echo  exec('/usr/bin/myscript');
```

But it is not working in browser, it is working fine in terminal.

Please tell me what is wrong.

Thanks

Comment: Make sure that the linux user under which the server runs has access to the folder. Depending on the system and the web server in use, the relevant user could be either nginx, www-data, etc.

Comment: Is the file `source.jpg` in the PHP script's working directory?

Comment: add `2>&1` to the end of the shell command in `exec()`, so you see error messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of things to try:

CHMOD the script to 777

Use the full server path to your bash script - You are doing that; I just added this in case somebody reads this and did not know that.

Why the echo in the php code?

```
<?php exec('bash /usr/bin/myscript'); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this would work. Running a bash script in the browser would be considered as a security vulnarability. Imagine if this could be achieved then, literally your PC can be controlled by any website/script. So, I don't think this is possible.

Comment: PHP runs on the server, not the client. I think he just wants to use a browser to start the script on the server.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use full path to source and destination files:

```
#!/bin/sh
convert /tmp/source.jpg -define jpeg:extent=256kb /tmp/destination.jpg;
```